# Is there a word for the hatred or fear of androids?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm specifically thinking of an AI, robot or android with near-human intelligence. The kind that you'd expect to see as a major character on a sci-fi show, acting almost indistinguishably from the humans, except for being really good with computers, then in one episode having to argue that he/she (it?) should have the same basic rights as all the human characters.

So, is there a word for someone prejudiced against or afraid of non-organic beings such as androids?

P.S. The motivation was [this SFF chat comment](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/23320879#23320879), which uses the term "racism" in reference to Data (from Star Trek: TNG) being passed up for promotion. That doesn't seem like the right term to me, but I can't think of a better one.

Comment: In common speech, racism is thrown around for other, different bigotries, like speciesism. In my specific instance, its was partly in jest.

Comment: @cde Yep, I'm just curious if there is a more specific term.

Comment: _Androidophobia_, no? _Androphobia_ already means fear of men.

Comment: @JohnLawler fear of men vs hatred of men (misandry). Fear of AI would likely be technophobia, if not limited to sentient/near sentient AI. OP is asking for hatred/bigotry, not phobia.

Comment: @JohnLawler are words that might be found in fantasy or science fiction on topic?

Comment: Robophobia seems to be forcing its way into the lexicon.

Comment: @cde "[A]re words that might be found in fantasy or science fiction on topic?" If you use 'word' to mean 'any string that some author may have used', the answer is 'Not all of them'. But I wouldn't accept that as a sensible definition of 'word' in any case.

Comment: Fear of work? As for F/SF, making up new words is the job of the author, and it's a hard job. Anticipating Norma Loquendi is much harder than getting geology or climate right. There's an [xkcd on the subject](https://xkcd.com/483/).

Comment: `Automatonophobia is the fear of anything that falsely represents a sentient being` That seems closer.

Comment: @cde Wow, that's a good find. Perhaps it should be an answer.

Comment: For reference, Asimov called it the "Frankenstein complex".

Answer (score 1):

The word "automatonophobia" covers a fear of some robots.  It comes from combining *automatos* (neuter, *automaton*) meaning "acting on its own" with *phobos*, meaning fear.  But it also applies to a fear of any representation of a sentient being -- ventriloquists' dummies, dolls, wax figures, and so on.  Of course, not all robots look like androids

The word at least has the purity of etymological descent from Greek, which is more than can be said for "robotphobia" and "robophobia," which have some cyberpresence.  The word "robot" comes from the Czech word *robota*, meaning forced labor or drudgery, and was coined by Czech writer Karel Čapek for his 1921 play *R.U.R.* (*Rossum's Universal Robots*).

Comment: Well, we can use the time-honored tradition of back-formation to extract a combining Grecoid form *robo-* from the already-established word *robotic* (compare with *necrotic* and *necrophobia*). Is the combining form of *automaton* really *automotono-*? I thought the *-on* was just the neuter suffix, not a part of the stem. @Cerberus might know.

Comment: In fact, I'm almost sure that isn't the correct classical combining form: compare to "bacterion," which has the combining form "bacterio-". I think the coiners of "automatonophobia" just got confused because the suffix in "automaton" was not Latinized the way it was in "bacterium." So it seems to me that a "pure" derivation from Ancient Greek would require "automatophobia" instead.

Answer (score 1):

I'll advocate for **robophobia**, which seems to me to be an understandable and well-formed word. (In contrast, the similar word *robotphobia* seems to me ill-formed and phonetically awkward).

True, "[robot](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/robot?q=robot)" is not originally from Greek; but there are already words in English that use a pseudo-Greek stem *robo-*. We have *[robotic](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/robotic?q=robotic)/[robotics](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/robotics?q=robotics)* and *[robotize](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/robotize),* as well as a fairly productive combining form *robo-* that as far as I can tell can be prefixed to pretty much any noun ([Robocall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocall), [Robodog](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3501062/), [Robocop](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0093870/?ref_=fn_al_tt_2), [Robo-Advisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robo-Advisor)).

So it seems to me to be available for new coinages.

Here are a few attested examples of "robophobia" in the wild:

- http://www.robots-and-androids.com/Robophobia.html
- https://www.wordnik.com/words/robophobia
- http://www.popsci.com/robots4us-darpas-response-mounting-robophobia-adorable

(hat tip to [Edwin Ashworth](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/21655/edwin-ashworth)'s comment)